# Lightweight cryptographic hash function for motes

Tags: hash, embedded, microcontroller, contiki

I need to use a cryptographic hash function for security and message integrity purposes in resource constrained devices like [tmote sky](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~konrad/projects/shimmer/references/tmote-sky-datasheet.pdf) or [z1 mote](http://zolertia.sourceforge.net/wiki/images/e/e8/Z1_RevC_Datasheet.pdf). I am using cooja simulator in contiki.

I tried to use [quark](https://github.com/veorq/Quark/blob/master/quark.c) or [blake2](https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/blob/master/ref/blake2b-ref.c). But `Section TEXT will not fit in region ROM`. I am sure the rest of the code is minimal with respect to memory requirement. So I need to use a still more lightweight hash function.

Using too much memory is causing the issue. For example, in case of quark [these](https://github.com/veorq/Quark/blob/master/quark.c#L198-L200) lines demand too much memory to be allocated.

Do you know of any hash function lightweight enough to fit on the motes?

Comment: Do you need the hash function for security or for other purposes? Cryptographical quality hashing has different requirement than "normal" hashing.

Comment: @kfx: For security purpose.

Comment: You could use encryption (all the typical motes have hardware accelerated AES-128) to produce message integrity checks by encryption the messages and a nonce with a chained block cypher.

Comment: Where can I find an open source C implementation to do the same?

Comment: You may look at how the MIC is generated here: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/lib/ccm-star.c

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni :  The purpose and constraints of your hash need to be in the question, not added as comments (_edit the question to add the information_).  A "lightweight hash" is a [simple problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function); a cyrptographically secure hash is a different matter and requires suitable expertise.  The two requirements are possibly mutually exclusive.

Comment: Since various hash algorithms are widely published, this question is of the "recommend a..." variety and therefore probably off-topic.  It will generate opinion based advice from a wide selection of possibilities.  Work you really need to do your self - people will recommend from experience rather then your requirements (not least because you have not stated any requirements).

Comment: @Clifford : As I spoke about quark and blake, the question is implicitly dealing with cryptographic hash function. But as per your say, I have edited the question. Now the question is specific and is no more off-topic or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: The Blake2 code you linked could be significantly smaller with `ROUND()` and `G()` defined as functions rather then macros - the in-lining of the macros expands to a lot of repeated code.  The Quark code includes `printf()` debug code is `DEBUG` is defined - that will increase the size significantly.  Look at the map file, or linker output to determine how much smaller it needs to be to fit - that would make a better SO question in any case.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni : It is only implicit f you have  cryptographic  expertise - without being explicit you may be inviting a number of irrelevant answers from helpful souls who have only ever used hashing for other purposes.  The question was asked, so it is _implicitly_ non-obvious; you provided the information, but should have used it to improve the question - that is what comments in SO are primarily for.  I did not however mark it off-topic because of lack of clarity; the phrase _"Do you know..."_ is inviting opinion.

Comment: @Clifford: Thanks for helping me make the question better.

Comment: What are you going to use the hashes for? Depending on this, a MAC may or may not be suitable instead. If you have hardware-accelerated AES, you may be able to build a cheap MAC on top of this. What hardware acceleration do you actually have? How much memory for code and for data?

Comment: @Gilles: As suggested by kfx, I am trying to use https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/lib/ccm-star.c. Looks like Cooja has no support for the hardware-implemented AES implementation. Need to go with software implementation of AES.